# Popover on hover always show up

Tags: css

I have the following CSS code, which is supposed to produce a popover when I hover over a button.

```
.qs {
  background-color: #02bdda;
  border-radius: 16px;
  color: #e3fbff;
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 25px;

  .popover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 42px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 4;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1em;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;


    &:before {
        border-top: 7px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
        border-right: 7px solid transparent;
        border-left: 7px solid transparent;
        bottom: -7px;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -7px;
        position: absolute;
      }
  }

  &:hover {
      .popover {
        display: block;
        -webkit-animation: fade-in .3s linear 1, move-up .3s linear 1;
        -moz-animation: fade-in .3s linear 1, move-up .3s linear 1;
        -ms-animation: fade-in .3s linear 1, move-up .3s linear 1;
      }
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
    from   { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in {
    from   { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fade-in {
    from   { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-up {
    from   { bottom: 30px; }
    to { bottom: 42px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes move-up {
    from   { bottom: 30px; }
    to { bottom: 42px; }
}
@-ms-keyframes move-up {
    from   { bottom: 30px; }
    to { bottom: 42px; }
}
```

However the popover shows up when the page loads instead of on hover. I guess I am missing something but I can't figure out the problem. The code was originally found at http://codepen.io/derekpcollins/pen/JCLhG/

Comment: This works exactly like you want it for me. The popup doesn't show until its on hover.

Comment: The codepen above is the original one. @Winston changed his CSS in this Stackoverflow post but not the codepen. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the display in `.popup` to `display: none`